# Can we read and assert on response in cypress cy.route Function?

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

I couldn't find anything in the documentation about asserting on the xhr response on the page.
Would like to know how it could be achieved in code?

Comment: use the call back function on the xhr response

Comment: Hi Prany, can you please elaborate with code?

Comment: sorry just seen now, it is now answered using the call back, which I meant earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use **expect** 
let's suppose that you set up the cypress server as below:

```
cy.server()
cy.route({<your route details>}).as('aliasName')
```

Then later in the code, you can use

```
cy.wait('@aliasName').then(xhr => {
  expect(xhr.responseBody.<your Item>).to.eql('something')
})
```